# wso2esb: can I use my own way to build a page that can add new proxy services?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

wso2esb is based on a datasource, at first I thought that the data stored by the datasource contains the proxy service what is added by the wso2esb console, but I didn't find 
corresponding data in that database, that is a big trouble for me.

Some users told me that the ui of wso2esb console is too complex and professional, so I want to build new pages that can let them add new proxy services and the methods are based on the original methods of wso2esb;

Is there original codes of method that can help me with this?

I read the source code of wso2esb, but I didn't know how it handle the data from the webpage and how the data user input saved.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, wso2esb deploys service automatically, if you put file in right directory. I advice to create artifact with UI, name it and then search in wso2esb home directory. 
For example, directory for services: $CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services

Although, I think that creating of UI with similar functionality is very strange idea and could be very hard.